# Match a string(input text from user) with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement where there is a customet name text box and the user able to input customer name to search customer. And the condition is user can add do wild card search putting * either infront or after the customer name. And the customer name should be minimum three characters long. I am using Regex to validate the user entry. 
Now in case the input is like  "*aaa*" .. I am validate this type of input using the following regex :

> [*]{1}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[*]{1}

The code is like below:

```js
    var str = "*aaa*";
    var patt = new RegExp("[*]{1}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[*]{1}");
    var res = patt.test(str);  
    alert(res);
```

```js
    var str = "*aaa***";
    var patt = new RegExp("[*]{1}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[*]{1}");
    var res = patt.test(str);  
    alert(res);
```

```js
    var str = "*aaa*$$$$";
    var patt = new RegExp("[*]{1}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[*]{1}");
    var res = patt.test(str);  
    alert(res);
```

Now for the input "*aaa*" res is coming true. But for this type of inputs also "*aaa**", "*aaa*$" its comimg true. And this expected as these expressions also contains the part( *aaa*) which satisfies the regex.But these inputs("*aaa**", *aaa*$** etc. ) are wrong.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong ? is there any issue with the regex or the way checking  is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:[*]([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){3,}[*])$
```

Use anchors `^$` to disable partial matching.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/17

Comment: Could you please explain me what changes u did... ^$ these u used so that the whole string is matched againts the regex. But why u have used ?:

Comment: @Sambuddha when you dont use `^$` regex will make partial matches .from `*aaa**` it will match `*aaa*` and pass.When you add anchors it wont unless complete string is matched

Comment: I guess `^[*][a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}[*]$` is a much better way to write this regex. With `i` option, it is even shorter: `/^[*][a-z0-9]{3,}[*]$/i`.

Answer (score 1):

The string `*aaa*$$$` contains a segment of `*aaa*`, so it will yield `true`; to match against the whole string you need to add anchors on both sides. The `$` and `^` anchors assert the start and end of the subject respectively.

Also, you can simply the expression greatly by using a character class trick. The `\w` is comprised of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, and we only don't want the underscore, so we can use a negative character class with the opposite of `\w` (which is `\W`) and an underscore; I agree, it takes some mental power ;-)

```js
var str = "*aaa*$";
    var patt = /^\*[^\W_]{3,}\*$/;
    var res = patt.test(str);  
    alert(res); // false
```

Alternatively, you can merge all your character classes together into one like so:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```